# How can i open a file such that its length should be multiple of 94

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I would like to open a file using open file dialog. If the opened file length is a multiple of 94 i would like to open that file if not i would like to throw an error message

Comment: makes me curious why you'd want to do that. are you serializing objects? and this is some kind of a check to make sure the file isn't corrupt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(new FileInfo(path).Length % 94 == 0)
{
   using(var reader = new StreamReader(path))
   {
       ...
   }
}
else 
    throw new ArgumentException("File-length not multiple of 94", "path");
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange question! How about....

```
if( file.Length % 94 ) throw.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if (new FileInfo(filename).Length % 94 != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

You may want to set `OpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists` to true, too - or do a manual check before taking the length.